# Flask web api is not working even when nginx and uwsgi is up and running

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, uwsgi, vmware-workstation

I have Ubuntu 16.04 on VMware workstation 12 player and my desktop is Windows 10. I have created a simple Flask web api and using nginx and uwsgi. Same application is working on my Azure Ubuntu 16.04 VM without any problem.

I have not made any changes in code I brought all the files from Azure VM via scp from my local VMware VM. But still app is not working. I have followed steps given in following URLs:

I have executed all the step accept last step, instead of creating uWSGI Emperor I created systemd service

https://vladikk.com/2013/09/12/serving-flask-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/convert-run-at-startup-script-from-upstart-to-systemd-for-ubuntu-16

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

Web api is working when i am running it from terminal using "python3 MLService.py &" command. which means flask along with my code has no issue. it is some thing with uwsgi and nginx.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer do you have solution to my problem?

Comment: I doubt "not working" is going to be sufficient for anyone to help. Are you able to gather up some logs or other observations to explain why the server might not be starting?

Comment: No, when i hit the url of my web api it is giving 404 method not found error..

Comment: Please add that information into the question (comments can be deleted at any time, and it is helpful for readers to see all the information in the question).